# recylerView.getItemCount() return only visible on screen items count

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a `RecylerView` I want to change active position items view with using `recylerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)`

my problem starts here

if i scroll to recylerview and position not show on screen 
i call `recylerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)` and this method return `null`

How can I load all adapter data once and use

```
for(i = 0; i<adapter.size(); i++){
     View v = recylerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView;
}
```

Comment: on RecyclerView you need to use holder.getAdpaterPosition() and not the position from the function itself

Comment: `load all adapter data`? what you mean by that?

Comment: you `for loop` always return null because it not contains all view at a single time as per your scroll views are added and removed

Comment: @pskink I want access all datas views with
recylerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position) 
but this method return only visible items view others always return null.

Comment: @BurakDurmuş why to access all **views**?

Comment: @BurakDurmuş **return only visible items view others always return null** because `recyclerview` add only items that are visible in screen when you scroll `Recyclerview` views are added and removed

Comment: @Pritesh-ɥsǝʇᴉɹꓒ I must be change active items view when button pressed. if user change list positon I couldn't access this item. How to fix it.

Comment: `I want access all datas views` its not possible - the whole idea of `RecyclerView` is that it recycles views when you scroll its content

Answer (score 0):

To make changes to the `RecyclerView`, you need to change its `Adapter`. It is not possible by design to modify the `RecyclerView` child views by hand.

If you want to change the active position, you could have a `int activePosition` member in your `Adapter` and call `adapter.notifynotifyDataSetChanged()` when you change it.

Answer (score 0):

recylerView.getAdapter().getCount();

may be it help you.